# Django-contrib-comments fails to get attribute `get_username()` of authenticated user

Tags: python, django

I'm currently implementing [django-contrib-comments](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments) and the `post_comment` view can't grab the attribute `get_username()` of the authenticated user. I attached the comment form to my object `poller` which itself has a foreign key to my user model `Account`.

> AttributeError at /comments/post/
> 'Account' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'

```
class Poller(models.Model):
    poller_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    [..]
```

The `post_comment` view fails here:

```
def post_comment(request, next=None, using=None):
    data = request.POST.copy()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not data.get('name', ''):
                data["name"] = request.user.get_full_name() or request.user.get_username() # fails here
```

My custom user model inherited from `AbstractBaseUser`:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    [..]
```

Comment: It is because you are using `AbstractBaseUser`,  `get_full_name` is not present there(*to put in simple words*). See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser

Comment: hm but shouldn't `or request.user.get_username()` heal it since `get_username()` is existent in AbstractBaseUser

Comment: No,  `get_full_name()` raised an exception, so `or` isn't gonna work

Comment: how does `or` work here?

Comment: It doesn't even reach the `or` part because of the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbstractBaseUser` removes the `get_full_name` method, so you must do it on your own. Something like this:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    [...]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

Comment: that worked, thanks! (I adapted it to return f'{self.username) in my case